# C Files triying to overwrite

Tags: c, file, mode

i'm having a bit of a headache with this code:

```
 FILE usuaris*
 ....

 usuaris=fopen("usuarisfinal.txt","a+b");
 fseek(usuaris,(pos-1)*sizeof(Tusuari),SEEK_SET);
 fwrite(&usuaux,sizeof(Tusuari),1,usuaris);
```

What i want to do is to overwrite a Tusuari register with "usuaux" in the position "pos", but I end up  adding "usuaux" at the end of the file. I'm aware that changing the mode "a+b" to "r+b" i'm able to do what i want, but i don't quite understand why i'm unable to make it work this  way!

P.S. Sorry for the possible mistakes, english is kind of a third language for me!

Comment: you opened the file with `a` (append)`  so all write operations will append to the file. That is the root of the problem.  Using a `mode` of Read Plus Binary:("r+b")  says 1) I want to read the file.  2) I want to write to the file at what ever the current file position indicator.  and 3) I want to perform all read and write operations using 'binary', (no special handling of newlines, etc.  Also do not want to use "w+b" as opening for `write` will result in the file being truncated during the `fopen()`

Answer (score 3):

When you open a file with mode `"a+"`, writes will always go to the end of the file.

From the [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fopen) for `fopen`:

> a+  Open for reading and appending (writing at end  of  file).   The
>       file is created if it does not exist.  The initial file position
>       for reading is at the beginning  of  the  file,  but  **output  is
>       always appended to the end of the file.**

When opening a file in this mode, setting the offset only affect reads.  So using mode `"r+"` is what you want.